# Generic Function Constraints? Should they cause a compile time error

Tags: typescript

I would expect the following code to throw a compile type error but it doesn't.

```
interface Service {
}

abstract class TestService implements Service {
}

class TestServiceImpl extends TestService {

}

class Blah {

}

function getService<T extends Service>(service: T): string {
    return 'hello';
}

let m = getService( Blah );
```

The compiler seems perfectly happy having a type that doesn't extend Service passed into getService when I would expect the T extends Service constraint to stop that. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

So changing getService to have a proper body that references its parameter made no difference.

Changing the Service interface to have something in it does, kinda makes sense but different to what I'm used to on other languages.

Now the issue is the following code has an error but just not what I expected

```
interface Service {
    doSomething(): number;
}

abstract class TestService implements Service {
    public doSomething(): number {
        return 1;
    }
}

class TestServiceImpl extends TestService {
    public doSomethingElse(): void {
        //
    }
}

function getService<T extends Service>(service: T): string {
    return (<any>service).name;
}

let m = getService( TestService );
```

I now get the error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof TestService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Service'.
>     Property 'doSomething' is missing in type 'typeof TestService'.
>   let m = getService( TestService );

Clearly TestService implements Service?

Obviously being a bit dumb here

Comment: 1. `TestService` and `TestServiceImpl` are irrelevant to the question. 2. `Blah` **does** meet the `Service` interface, which is... nothing. If you add a property or method to `Service` that `Blah` lacks, the compiler complains as expected.

Comment: I had the same issue once before. You need to at least use the parameter once in the method body. Very confusing I agree.

Comment: Note that even if Service was a real interface and Blah implemented it, the method would expect an **instance** of Service. So you would need `getService(new Blah())`.

Answer (score 2):

`getService(Blah)` is actually passing in the *declaration* `Blah` which I think is essentially just a function. I believe you mean to pass `getService(new Blah)`.

In TypeScript, types do not have to be declared to extend each other. It just does a check to see whether the interfaces conform. Since `Service` has no properties pretty much anything will conform to it. You could even do something like `getService(1)` or `getService(false)` and it wouldn't cause a TypeScript error.

As another example, you could do: `let blah: Service = new Blah(); getService(blah)`. TypeScript does the coercion for you.

If `Service` had properties, then `Blah` would have to match those properties:

```
interface Service { a: string; }
class Blah { }
getService(new Blah()); // error - Type 'Blah' is not assignable to type 'Service'
class BetterBlah { a: string; }
getService(new BetterBlah()); // works -- interfaces conform
```

That is to say interfaces in TypeScript are *advisory*. I think this has to do with interoperability with JavaScript and object variable declarations. For example using the `Service` type above you could also do:

```
getService({ a: 'value' });
```

Comment: Ahh got it... just commented on my original post before I saw yours.  I did intend to pass the type and not a new instance

Comment: Your update essentially turns this into a different question .. types do not have implementations so `TestService` doesn't have `doSomething`, but `new TestService` (if that were allowed) does.